# Clipboard link pastes into WYSIWYG as code/text instead of link

Tags: javascript, wysiwyg, tampermonkey

I have this in a Tampermonkey script:

```
var journey_link = "<a href='http://www.google.co.uk'>Google</a>";
//...
GM_setClipboard (journey_link);
```

But when I paste into a WYSIWYG editor, the contents appear as code.

Is it possible to display as the intended hyperlink? Or is this a limitation of WYSIWYG?

Thanks

Comment: `GM_setClipboard(journey_link, 'html');` as per the [documentation](https://tampermonkey.net/documentation.php#GM_setClipboard).

Comment: Legend. Worked a charm. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As wOxxOm said, set `GM_setClipboard`'s `info` parameter to `'html'`:

```
GM_setClipboard (journey_link, 'html');
```

This will cause most WYSIWYG editors to treat it as a link, rather than text.

Reference:  [The Tampermonkey doc for GM_setClipboard](https://tampermonkey.net/documentation.php#GM_setClipboard).

Note that only **Tampermonkey and Violentmonkey currently support this.**  Greasemonkey does not.